# Are the hidden default timeouts in Angular 5?

Tags: .net, angular, timeout

Currently working on a .NET / Angular 5 app, querying an (T)-SQL database hosted on Azure.

Everything works fine on the backend, and on the frontend for queries finishing under 60s. But if they reach 60s exactly, it just stops and returns empty with no errors shown.

Current workaround of splitting the queries so they finish under a minute works, but that's not ideal. Checked all timeouts that were set, but none are set to 60 seconds.
My assumption is I'm running into some default timeout of 60s somewhere, but I've been unable to find it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using .net app with angular so it could be there are some timeout config from BE side (for example JWT token timeout)